# Deleted vue component still throwing error when server is started

Tags: vue.js, debugging, compiler-errors, frontend, runtime-error

I am trying to follow along with a vue project tutorial as I am new to the vue development environment. When I delete the hellovue component as done in the tutorial since it is a component I will not be needing and deleting all the instances where the component is called in the project, My server keeps throwing this error

ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 1:0-53
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/HelloWorld.vue' in 'C:\Users\HP Laptop\documents\coding\vue_projects\resto-project\src'

I have tried checking that I have deleted all the instances where that component was called. I have tried restarting the project severally, I have also checked my vue version

Comment: It's unknown if you really deleted it. Search the project for "Hello". If the problem persists, delete node_modules/.cache before starting devserver, could be caused by cached data